# dtutil import ssis package from remote

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, ssis

I am trying to import an ssis package (.dtsx) from one server to another remotely but I face a strange issue. (dtsx is on Server-02 and need to be imported on Server-01)

Let me explain with 3 commands :

**Running on Server-01**

```
osql  -E -h  -Q "select name from  [msdb].[dbo].[sysssispackages] where name like '%MIC%'"
```

This returns nothing, my package is not imported yet, that's ok.

I have a .bat file on Server-01 which contains the following command :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\dtutil.exe" /FILE \\Server-02\D$\BAM_DM_IBZMICVU001.DTSX /COPY SQL;BAM_DM_IBZMICVU001 /QUIET
```

DTSX is located in D:\ on Server-02, .bat file is located in D:\ on Server-01.
This bat file must be run in order to import the ssis package.

**Then running on Server-02**

```
WMIC /NODE:"Server-01" process call create "cmd.exe /A /C D:\\BAM_DM_IBZMICVU001.bat"
```

It returns successful state. But then when I run again on Server-01 my osql command, it still returns 0 result. It seems the package hasn't been imported...

We could think that the bat file isn't working but if I run the bat file directly by double clic on Server-01, it also runs successfuly. Then I do the osql select, it returns 1 result, the package has been imported successfuly.

At this moment, I thought that the bat script was simply not executed remotely. So I changed it a little.

```
echo "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\dtutil.exe" /FILE \\Server-02\D$\BAM_DM_IBZMICVU001.DTSX /COPY SQL;BAM_DM_IBZMICVU001 /QUIET > D:\debug.txt
```

**Then from Server-02**

```
WMIC /NODE:"Server-01" process call create "cmd.exe /A /C D:\\BAM_DM_IBZMICVU001.bat"
```

D:\debug.txt has been successfuly created on Server-01 which means the bat script also executed well...

Any idea of what could happen in my case ?

Comment: Did the package get deployed to server-02? If you provide an explicit `/DestServer server-01` to the batch script, does the package get deployed as expected?

Comment: Same result unfortunately...

Comment: You have a lot of layers here where things can go awry here: Permissions, pathing, etc. If you strip the echo but leave in the output redirect `dtutil.exe ... > D:\debug.txt` what text is generated as part of the deploy. I _think_ `/quiet` only suppresses the prompt to overwrite but it's been ages since I dealt with msdb deploys